# Block sequence codewars kata

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, numbers

I have a problem with [Block sequence](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e1ab1b9fe268c0033680e5f/train/java) kata in code wars I tried to solve using recursion, but my code is slow.

My idea was to count from `1` to auxiliary variable `c`, then set integers in `String ss=""` and then count from `c` to `n`.

```
public static int solve(long n){
    //..
    String ss="";
    long count=1;
    char c=find(n,count,ss);
    ss="";
    ss+=c;
    return Integer.parseInt(ss);
}

static char find(long n,long c,String ss) {
    
    if(c>n) 
        return ss.charAt((int)n-1);
    
    else {
        for(long i=1;i<=c;i++) 
            ss+=i;
        return find(n,c+1,ss);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what would you like help with? Increasing the speed?

Comment: byte[] operations are faster than the string stuff, barring method overhead, but I'm not sure how low the kata's time threshold is. I assume you'd have to calculate the correct element of the original array and the correct index in the element arithmetically, without using a recursive calculation like you do now. There's a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) for the sum of the different lenghts of your elements up to a number (1,2,3,4...n), sum = (n*(n+1))/2, perhaps you can start from there.

Comment: yes, each of the resulting sums is also called a triangular number, you need the index i of the smallest of them which is > n. the array element will be of length i, construct it in some way and take about the (n-p)th character. You can find the procedure [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-triangular-number-larger-than-p/). about that.